Is there any efficient way to compute the sum of vectors?
Assume $n$ parties each has a secret vector $v_i$,How to compute the value of $\sum v_i$ correctly without disclosing the secret vectors under the malicious adversary model?

Hint: the sum of vectors is a vector which coordinates are obtained by summing the respective coordinates of each vector, thus the problem reduces to summing coordinates.

thank you! so is there any solution to summing coordinates?

When coordinates are bounded integers, see this related question.
